# ESP - Nodemcu amica - attachInterrupt crash program

Tags: esp8266, interrupt, nodemcu, debugging

I get new boards from the shop but they are little different from the previous version. I got software what works ok on Nodemcu lolin v3 now I get Nodemcu Amica what is almost same board but if I got attachInterrupt function in the program it crashes immediately.

```
    attachInterrupt(6, bowlingCall, RISING);
//attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(D1), statekCall, RISING);
```

I try different pins but not change. I debug all program(comment all out and left just attachInterrupt and it crashes again).

```
    ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,6)

load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16
tail 8
chksum 0x2d
csum 0x2d
v8b899c12
~ld
```

The board cycle in the reboot sequence, even serial output do not work ok. Why did esp crash at attachInterupt on this board?

Comment: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/6142

Answer (score 1):

thanks @Juraj.

Ok, so all you need is rewrite all your interrupt function.
For example:

```
void getStatusFromMaster()
```

to

```
void ICACHE_RAM_ATTR getStatusFromMaster()
```